# How to create a random integer array generator

Tags: java, android, random, arraylist

I have created a method which takes generate random numbers with the condition that the next random number doesn't match with the previous one inside the array here's the code

```
// some code   

int k=0;

//some code....

randomgenerator(k); // method call

public void randomgenerator(int j)
{

    for(j=0; j<=99; j++){
        if(j >= 1){
            if (randomset.get(j) == randomset.get(j-1)){
                randomset.add(0 + ( j  ,  int)(Math.random() * ((99 - 0) + 1)));
            }
            else{
                randomset.add(0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((99 - 0) + 1)));
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

The error I get is  **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1**

Comment: Please tabulate the code correctly; it is hard to read, and I think there is a missing  }

Comment: Is it because your array is empty to begin with? YET your trying to READ it here... "if (randomset.get(j) == randomset.get(j-1)){"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because initially randomset is empty therefore its size is 0 and returns exception at index 1. The best way to add `randomset.add(0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((99 - 0) + 1)));` if `j < 1` (not >=1).

Correct code:

```
public void randomgenerator(int j)
{
for(j=0; j<=99; j++){
    if(j >= 1){
        if (randomset.get(j) == randomset.get(j-1)){
            randomset.add(0 + ( j  ,  int)(Math.random() * ((99 - 0) + 1)));
        }
        else{
            randomset.add(0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((99 - 0) + 1)));
        }
    }
    else {
           randomset.add(0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((99 - 0) + 1)));
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: If I implement the above looping conditions the lopp will not end since the data is inserted inside the loop so the randomset.size would go on increasing. but I need only 99 values.

Comment: O have modified my solution. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 for(j=0; j<randomset.size(); j++){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference an element of `ArrayList` whose index is not in bounds `[0, size() - 1]`. Creating `ArrayList` via `ArrayList()` creates a list of size `0`. To add elements to this array you must call one of the methods that adds an element, e.g. `add()`. Your first call is to `get()`, but the list has size `0`, so even `get(0)` will cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

What to do depends on the expected contents of the list. In your case, I would recommend writing a helper function that generates a random number in range *excluding* specified number. You could use that function in a simple loop to generate the whole list, passing previous element to mentioned helper function.

Example:

```
public static int randomInRange(int a, int b) {
    return (int)(Math.random() * (b - a + 1));
}

public static int randomInRangeExcluding(int a, int b, int excluding) {
    int result = (int)(Math.random() * (b - a));
    if (result == excluding) {
        result++;
    }
    return result;
}

public static List<Integer> generateRandomList(int size) {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int j = 0; j <= size; j++) {
        if (j > 0) {
            result.add(randomInRangeExcluding(0, size - 1, result.get(j - 1)));
        } else {
            result.add(randomInRange(0, size - 1));
        }    
    }
    return result;
}
```

and get the value using:

```
generateRandomList(100);
```

Calling this results in a list of random integers having no two consecutive elements equal:

```
[27, 34, 53, 92, 56, 93, 21, 22, 45, 95, 48, 25, 18, 26, 54, 1, 82, 26, 5, 62, 84, 23, 8, 84, 25, 0, 36, 37, 54, 95, 4, 26, 65, 53, 81, 16, 47, 56, 73, 46, 60, 50, 37, 89, 61, 84, 23, 79, 47, 87, 68, 49, 15, 17, 55, 71, 17, 55, 71, 51, 67, 33, 80, 47, 81, 24, 10, 41, 76, 60, 12, 17, 96, 43, 57, 55, 41, 56, 21, 85, 98, 40, 9, 39, 53, 28, 93, 70, 89, 80, 40, 41, 30, 81, 33, 53, 73, 28, 38, 87, 29]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the same variable as your input parameter and your loop variable.

public void randomgenerator(int length)
{

for (int j = 0; j < length; j ++) ...

I'm not sure I follow the rest of the code, but that's a start.

Answer (score 0):

What is with you're function? You receive a parameter named **j** and then you reassigned it?

randomset.get(j) == randomset.get(j-1) <- at this line you have a **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException** because you call for the value from position 1 but in you're list you have only a value on position 0; so an error is thrown

and, what is this ? **((99 - 0) + 1))** ,you could white 100, it is easy, and more readable

by the way, at this line you have an error,  **randomset.add(0 + ( j  ,  (int)(Math.random() * ((99 - 0) + 1)));**

You should write a cleaner code.

I've prepared a solution for you: a function which generates a List with random numbers and respects you condition: two consecutive numbers are not the same.

You must call this method **generateRandomList** with the number of elements you want to generate.

```
public static final Integer MAX_RANDOM_NUMBER = 100;


public static List<Integer> generateRandomList(int randomNumbers) {
    return generateRandomList(randomNumbers, -1);
}

private static List<Integer> generateRandomList(final int randomNumbers, final int previousNumber) {
    if (randomNumbers == 1) {
        return new ArrayList<Integer>() {
            {
                add(getNextNumber(previousNumber));
            }

        };
    } else {

        return new ArrayList<Integer>() {
            {
                int value = getNextNumber(previousNumber);
                add(value);
                addAll(generateRandomList(randomNumbers - 1, value));
            }

        };
    }
}

private static int getNextNumber(int previousNumber) {
    boolean generateNewValue = true;
    int currentValue = 0;
    while (generateNewValue) {
        currentValue = (int) (Math.random() * MAX_RANDOM_NUMBER);
        generateNewValue = currentValue == previousNumber;
    }
    return currentValue;
}
```